# Confusing Storm-UI

Tags: hadoop, apache-storm

I am confused by the Storm-UI statistics.

For example:

[image: Storm-UI]

**Topology Stats** show a number of 69 million

**kafka-spout** shows a number of 34 million

**__acker** is at 17 million

**es-bolt** shows 17 million too

My toplogy is kafka-spout --> es-bolt and I am not sure how the numbers above add up?

If Kafka-spout is emitting only 34 million, why do topology stats show 69 million?

And again if Kafka-spout emitted 34 million, why does es-bolt say 17 million?

I see a pattern of tuples being halved from top-to-down, but not sure I understand why? Is it because of ack-tuples or heart-beat bolts?

Are they always half of the upstream spout?

Answer (score 2):

You can turn off system stats, then numbers will make sense.
There's button on the bottom of Storm UI stats page.

Answer (score 0):

Topology Stats show a number of 69 million
   This is sum of all your spouts and bolts: 34.x + 17.x +17.x

And emitting numbers of the spout and bolt are not necessarily related. It's related to your code.

Comment: I do not have any code here, except the flux topology configuration file. So all messages coming from Kafka-Spout go to ES-Bolt. Is there anything else why the numbers do not match from Spout to Bolt ?

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that those metrics are sampled at the rate o of topology.stats.sample.rate, 0.05 by default. If you turn it up to 1.0 you'll see full-resolution, though at the price of more time spent collecting metrics.

Comment: Please do not post comments as answers.