# Storm UI data - Hide system stats / Show system stats

Tags: apache-storm

This is follow up question on [Confusing Storm-UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36106630/confusing-storm-ui)

After clicking on Hide system stats button, I was able to get the right values.

I don't understand the calculation behind the emitted, transferred and acknowledged when we click on Hide system stats / Show system stats button on storm UI